# Error: You must build Spark with Hive

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I'm running Spark 1.6.2 with Hive 0.13.1 and Hadoop 2.6.0.

I try to run this pyspark script:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sc = pyspark.SparkContext('local[*]')
hc = HiveContext(sc)
hc.sql("select col from table limit 3")
```

with this command line:

```
 ~/spark/bin/spark-submit script.py
```

and I got this error message:

```
 File "/usr/local/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line >552, in sql
 return DataFrame(self._ssql_ctx.sql(sqlQuery), self)
 File "/usr/local/hadoop/spark/python/pyspark/sql/context.py", line >660, in _ssql_ctx
 "build/sbt assembly", e)
 Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while >calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject >id=o18))
```

Doing what they asked, I saw a warning saying that "exporting SPARK_HIVE was deprecated" and to use instead "-Phive -Phive-thriftserver" 
So I did this:

```
 cd ~/spark/
 build/sbt -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver assembly
```

but I have slightly the same error:

```
 [...]
 16/07/17 19:10:01 WARN metadata.Hive: Failed to access metastore. This class should not accessed in runtime.
 org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate      org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient
     at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.Hive.getAllDatabases(Hive.java:1236)   
 [...]
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/home/hadoop/spark3/./script.py", line 6, in <module>
     hc.sql("select timestats from logweb limit 3")
   File "/usr/local/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py",      line 552, in sql
   File "/usr/local/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 660, in _ssql_ctx
 Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject id=o19))
```

I searched on the web about this error, but none if the answers worked for me...

Could someone help me please?

---

I also tried to use a [spark version which is suposed to work with Hadoop](http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.6.2/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz) (Suggested by [Joss](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38295021/error-you-must-build-spark-with-hive#answer-38295174)) , and I got this error :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/home/hadoop/spark3/./script.py", line 6, in <module>
hc.sql("select timestats from logweb limit 3")
 File "/usr/local/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 552, in sql
 File "/usr/local/hadoop/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/context.py", line 660, in _ssql_ctx
 Exception: ("You must build Spark with Hive. Export 'SPARK_HIVE=true' and run build/sbt assembly", Py4JJavaError(u'An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.\n', JavaObject id=o19))
```

Answer (score 0):

I have an Apache Spark version that came with HiveContext by default, this is the link to download in case you are interested:

- [Spark 1.6.2 with HiveContext](http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.6.2/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz)

Regarding the problem you have, it may be related to the version of Hadoop that you use to compile Spark. Check the parameters that relate to the version of Hadoop you require.

Comment: Hello Joss, what do you mean by "Check the parameters that relate to the version of Hadoop you require." ?

Comment: Hi.. [To this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-buildmvn). Example: `build/mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.4 -Dhadoop.version=2.4.0 -DskipTests clean package`. In that case the version of Hadoop used is 2.4.0. And for **sbt** you can check [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html#building-with-sbt).

Comment: Also, I think that `sc` in your script may give you some trouble later. You need to initialize the context. Reference: [link](https://gist.github.com/JosemyD/14831750a55233193524df1a47404c56)

Comment: Hi Joss, I downloaded the Spark version that comes with Hivecontext :

`wget http://www-eu.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-1.6.2/spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz`

`gunzip -c spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz | tar -xvf -`
`cd spark-1.6.2-bin-hadoop2.6` , but in this directory I don't see ./build/mvn ... how to do?

Comment: That version doesn't need to be build. Run $SPARK_HOME/bin/spark-submit directly. Remember to add the respective environment variables.

Comment: Hi Joss. Thank you again. I tried what you said and I still get the error (I updated my post). By the way, which environment variable should I add?

Comment: **SPARK_HOME**: Folder where you decompressed Apache Spark
**PATH**: Add $SPARK_HOME/bin to $PATH.
**PYTHONPATH**: $SPARK_HOME/python:$SPARK_HOME/python/lib/py4j-0.9-src.zip

Those are my variables. But it should be enough with the first 2. And I'm running exactly that version of Spark. If your interest is learning about the use of PySpark, I can recommend you [this Docker's image](https://github.com/jupyter/docker-stacks/tree/master/pyspark-notebook), It is very easy to install and start to testing, and also comes with everything pre-configured.